# Custom slot's available in builder with default components assigned

Tags: lightning-web-components, experience-cloud, digital-experience, experience-builder-page, slots

I have custom lwc with **slots** available in builder. Into slot's I put some custom lwc and ootb components (e.g User Profile menu or Commerce navigation)

The problem is when I try to change something inside this component(e.g. add new slot) or add this component to another experience, I have to add all componentns into slots again.
[image: empty slot in builder]
[image: slots]
Is there any option to have slots filled in by default, because when I tried to deploy something like that:

```
<slot>
<commerce_cart-badge></commerce_cart-badge>
</slot>
```

I see error that **no module named *commerce_cart-badge* was found**. With custom lwc inside despite deployment is successfull, component is not visible in community builder.